# Google Sheets Script for Creating Filter with Visible Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written the code but the issue is that it is checking the exact match means if some text is there but it is in lower case or upper case then the code is not working, please give the solution.

my code is

```
function FilterScript() {

  //CREATED BY PUNIT SINGHAL
  //FOR ACTIVATING SPREADSHEETAPP
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //FOR SELECTING SHEET BY ITS NAME
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'), true);

  //FOR CREATING FILTER
  //FILTER SCRIPT STARTS FROM HERE

  //EDIT THE FIELD AS PER REQUIREMENT
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:Q1002').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:Q1002').createFilter();
  var filterColumn = 'L2:L1002';                               //GIVE THE FILTER COLUMN RANGE OR 'F1:F'+spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  var visibleValues = ['Punit','Kirti',''];       //GIVE THE REQUIRED VISIBLE VALUES

  //DON'T EDIT THE BELOW CODE OF FILTER
  //FOR GETTING THE FILTER COLUMN NUMBER
  var filterColumnNo = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(filterColumn).getColumn();
  //FOR GETTING FILTER COLUMN VALUES
  var filterValues = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(filterColumn).getValues();
  //FOR GETTING HIDDEN VALUES
  var hidden = getHiddenValueArray(filterValues,visibleValues);
  //FOR BUILDING FILTER CRITERIA
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria().setHiddenValues(hidden).build();
  //FLATTENS AND STRIPS COLUMN VALUES OF ALL THE VALUES IN THE VISIBLE VALUE ARRAY
  function getHiddenValueArray(colValueArr,visibleValueArr){
  var flatUniqArr = colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0];})
  .filter(function(e,i,a){return (a.indexOf(e) == i && visibleValueArr.indexOf(e) == -1); })  //FOR HANDLING NUMERIC AND STRING VALUES
  return flatUniqArr;
  }
  //FOR APPLYING FINAL STEP OF FILTER
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(filterColumnNo, criteria);
  //FILTER SCRIPT ENDS AT HERE
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about `the code is not working`?

Answer (score 0):

### if some text is there but it is in lower case or upper case then the code is not working

This issue comes from the fact that [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is case-sensitive.

You can work around this limitation by setting e.g. both `visibleValues` and `filterValues` to lower case with [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase).

To do so, you can for example modify

`var visibleValues = ['Punit','Kirti',''];`

to

`var visibleValues = ['Punit','Kirti',''].map(e => e.toLowerCase());`

and

`colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0];})`

to

`colValueArr.map(function(e){return e[0].toLowerCase();})`